# Translation matrix in spherical coordinates system

Tags: spherical-coordinates, geodesy

I'm using WorldWind software to draw segments (*polyline*) on the globe to materialize an aircraft *flightplan*. Each point in a flightplan is named *waypoint*. Waypoints are expressed in geographical coordinates with a latitude a longitude (no altitude yet). I whish to draw an area 4000 meter width around the flightplan, name of this distance is *d*.

In Euclidian system it's trivial to compute the factor {dx,dy} of a translation matrix:

- alpha = atan2( ye-ys, xe-xs )
- dx = d * cos( alpha )
- dy = d * sin( alpha )

But I don't known how to compute {lat,lon} as {y,x} with spherical coordinates system.

Comment: See [Changing Coordinate Systems](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ChangingCoordinateSystems.html) and [List of common coordinate transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations), but are you sure you're posting on the correct site? This stackexchange site is about the program Mathematica and not about maths.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.